# BrowserSync может ли автоматически обновлять css?

Tags: css, вёрстка, browsersync

Здравствуйте.
Правильно ли я понимаю, что BrowserSync не может автоматически изменять стили на сайте после изменений этих стилей в редакторе до тех пор пока я не сохранюсь в редакторе (cmd+s)? То есть BrowserSync не может работать также как Emmet LiveStyle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здравствуйте. Да, абсолютно правильно. BrowserSync синхронизирует, то что у вас сохранено в коде, с тем, что вы видите на экране. В обратном направлении он не работает, как вы верно подметили, такими функциями обладает Emmet Livestyle.